# How to use fscanf to reads any character into a string until a tab is reached?

Tags: c++, c

How to use fscanf to reads any character into a string until a tab is reached?

My data file have only 1 row:

```
123'\t'(Tab)345'\t'Le Duc Huy'\t'567
```

and i use fscanf like this:

```
fscanf(fin,"%d %d %d %[^\t]%s %d",&m,&n,&k,s,&q);
```

it return q with wrong value. Anybody can tell me what made it failed?

Comment: Note: When you put a space in the fscanf string this matches a *sequence* of white-space (space/tab/newline etc) characters.

Answer (score 2):

Using `fscanf()`, you will need a negated character class and a length:

```
char string[32];

if (fscanf(fp, "%31[^\t]", string) != 1)
    ...error or EOF...
```

---

The modified version of the question has a data string with a single quote after the final tab, and the single quote cannot be converted to an integer, so the value in `q` is undefined.  Note that you *must* check the return value of `fscanf()` to ensure that all the fields you expected to match actually did match,  In the context, if probably returned the value 4 instead of 5, telling you there was an error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `fscanf` I would just use `fgetc` (though my syntax may be off a bit):

```
int c;
string s = "";
for (;;)
{
    c = fgetc(somefile);
    if (c == '\t' || c == EOF) break;
    s += c;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off with a two-line while loop: `while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\t') s += c;`?  Especially since there is nothing else to go into the loop.

Comment: So, why would you use fgetc instead of fscanf?

Comment: Regarding the two-line loop, it's equivalent, but assignments within conditionals are generally evil and the longer way is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the `fscanf()` version:

```
fscanf (stream, "[^\t]", output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, this is not safe!

`char foo[100];
scanf("%s\t", foo);`

You have no way of keeping the user from overflowing the buffer

Comment: No, this also skips whitespaces.

Comment: It skips leading white spaces and stops at the first white space.  You can make it safe by specifying the size of the buffer in the format string.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate the space before `%[`. It's eating your tab. Also, as others have said, this code is unsafe and probably unreliable on input that's not formatted exactly as you expect. It would be better to use `fgets` and then parse it yourself with `strtol` and a few for loops.